# EF Core Add-Migration generating extra column with ColumnName1

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I have the following entities when I generate migration it creates two columns with name RestrictedCategoryId and RestrictedCategoryId1(FK). How to solve this issue to generate only one column with FK?

Note: I need OrderId in each entity.

`C#

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    private List<Category> _categories;
    public List<Category> Categories => _categories;
}
public class Category
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }

    private List<RestrictionCategory> _restrictedCategories;
    public List<RestrictionCategory> RestrictedCategories => _restrictedCategories;
}
public class RestrictionCategory
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }        
    public Guid RestrictedCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category RestrictedCategory { get; set; }
}
public class OrderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(o => o.Id);
        builder.Property(o => o.Id).IsRequired();
    }
}
public class CategoryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Category> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(c => new { c.Id, c.OrderId });
        builder.Property(o => o.Id).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(o => o.OrderId).IsRequired();

        builder.HasMany(c => c.RestrictedCategories).WithOne(cr => cr.Category)
            .HasForeignKey(cr => new { cr.CategoryId, cr.OrderId 
}).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}
public class RestrictionCategoryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<RestrictionCategory>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<RestrictionCategory> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(c => new { c.Id, c.OrderId });
        builder.Property(o => o.Id).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(o => o.OrderId).IsRequired();

        builder.HasIndex(cr => new { cr.RestrictedCategoryId, cr.OrderId });
    }
}
```

`
The entities resembles to actual ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you get two additional columns:

```
RestrictedCategoryId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
RestrictedCategoryId1 = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: true), // <--
RestrictedCategoryOrderId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: true) // <--
```

Apparently EF Core [Foreign Key Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#conventions) doesn't play well with composite keys, so you have to explicitly configure the relationship - similar to what you did for the other relationship, just since your model has no corresponding collection navigation property you have to use `HasMany` with generic type argument and no parameters, e.g. inside `CategoryConfiguration`:

```
builder.HasMany<RestrictionCategory>()
    .WithOne(cr => cr.RestrictedCategory)
    .HasForeignKey(cr => new { cr.RestrictedCategoryId, cr.OrderId})
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Comment: Correct, I missed it. It is creating two additional columns. And your solution worked like a charm. Thanks.